# AWS: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to download a file to sagemaker from my S3 bucket.

the path of the file is
`s3://vemyone/input/dicom-images-train/1.2.276.0.7230010.3.1.2.8323329.1000.1517875165.878026/1.2.276.0.7230010.3.1.3.8323329.1000.1517875165.878025/1.2.276.0.7230010.3.1.4.8323329.1000.1517875165.878027.dcm`

The path of that file is stored as a list element at `train_fns[0]`.

the value of `train_fns[0]` is

`input/dicom-images-train/1.2.276.0.7230010.3.1.2.8323329.1000.1517875165.878026/1.2.276.0.7230010.3.1.3.8323329.1000.1517875165.878025/1.2.276.0.7230010.3.1.4.8323329.1000.1517875165.878027.dcm`

I used the following code:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucketname = 'vemyone'

s3.Bucket(bucketname).download_file(train_fns[0][:], train_fns[0])
```

but I get the following error:

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'input/dicom-images-train/1.2.276.0.7230010.3.1.2.8323329.1000.1517875165.878026/1.2.276.0.7230010.3.1.3.8323329.1000.1517875165.878025/1.2.276.0.7230010.3.1.4.8323329.1000.1517875165.878027.dcm.5b003ba1'`

I notice that some characters have appended itself at the end of the path.

how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please see https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.download_file

by the doc, first argument is file key, second argument is path for local file:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucketname = 'vemyone'

s3.Bucket(bucketname).download_file(train_fns[0], '/path/to/local/file')
```

Comment: I get this`ClientError: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found`
`

Comment: I checked the key of the file i'm trying to download and it is exactly the value in 
 `train_fns[0]`

Comment: is there a chance that you are missing '/' before the file name? it looks like by the docs its required

Comment: i.e `/input/dicom-images-train/1.2.276.0.7230010.3.1.2.8323329.1000.1517875165.878026/1.2.276.0.7230010.3.1.3.8323329.1000.1517875165.878025/1.2.276.0.7230010.3.1.4.8323329.1000.1517875165.878027.dcm` instead of `input/dicom-images-train/1.2.276.0.7230010.3.1.2.8323329.1000.1517875165.878026/1.2.276.0.7230010.3.1.3.8323329.1000.1517875165.878025/1.2.276.0.7230010.3.1.4.8323329.1000.1517875165.878027.dcm`

Comment: the key value does not have a '/' in the beginning

Comment: lol it took me a while, but Filename (str) -- The path to the file to download to. its the *local* filepath you like to download the file to

Comment: from the documentation Filename (str) -- The path to the file to download to. You are passing the S3 file key instead the local folder which does not exists

Comment: I ran into the same issue - The folder needs to exist before the files will be downloaded. Or add some code to check whether the directory exists :)